# On click issue with when one Layout is INVISIBLE & the other Layout is VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have the following two LinearLayout in a layout xml.

I have added onClickListener on both the layout items layout_edit & layout_create

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView_edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" >
            </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_create"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layout_edit"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView_create"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_create" >
            </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added the following code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutEdit = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_edit);
mLinearLayoutEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

LinearLayout linearLayoutCreate = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_create);
linearLayoutCreate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

On a specific scenario , the following code is added:

linearLayoutEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Now , linearLayoutCreate is still visible , but linearLayoutCreate onClick is not working.

When both linearLayoutEdit & linearLayoutCreate  are VISIBLE , both their onClick are working fine.

It seems like since linearLayoutCreate is positioned left of linearLayoutEdit & linearLayoutEdit is made INVISIBLE using code, the clickable action of linearLayoutCreate is not working though its visible.

Any hints on how to make linearLayoutCreate clickable when linearLayoutEdit is INVISIBLE.

One solution which I found out is recreating the layout again using code with the already available id but is there any other solution available?

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.layout_edit:
            break;
        case R.id.layout_create:
                // not navigating within this condition only when layout_edit is INVISIBLE, but //navigating when both layout_edit & layout_create are VISIBLE
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set the visibility of `linearyLayoutEdit` to `gone` instead of `invisible`, because `invisible` will still hold the space.

Comment: Use "[edit]" to add the code to your question. As you noticed comments don't show code very well...

Comment: Does the `imgView_create` have any listeners attached to it (OnTouch, OnClick, etc)?

Comment: I have not added any onclicklistener/ontouchlistener since I want the entire layout to be clickable.

Comment: Everything that you have posted works, without the full `onClick` code, no one can help you...

Answer (score 0):

> Now , linearLayoutCreate is still visible , but linearLayoutCreate onClick is not working.

It sounds like you have setup *both* layouts to hide the *one* layout `linearLayoutEdit` when clicked, change your `onClick()` method to hide the layout that was clicked:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I cant change v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) at onClick(). At runtime , I check a condition & make linearLayoutEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) & linearLayoutCreate is VISIBLE but still linearLayoutCreate is not clickable. When both linearLayoutEdit & linearLayoutCreate are VISIBLE , both their onClick are working fine.

Comment: Post your `onClick` method in your question, it sounds like your condition check might not be right...